# Config ElasticSearch Magento 2.4 - No alive nodes found in your cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, nginx, magento2, nginx-config, proxypass

When trying to search for a product in magento 2.4 returns the following error

> Exception #0 (Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\NoNodesAvailableException): No alive nodes found in your cluster

Below configuration:

- PHP 7.4.1
- Nginx 1.14
- MySql 8
- ElasticSearch 7.9

/etc/nginx/conf.d/100-magento2.conf

```
upstream fastcgi_backend {
    server   unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
}
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name _;

  set $MAGE_ROOT /var/www/magento2;
  include /var/www/magento2/nginx.conf.sample;

}
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d/90-es.conf

```
upstream   elasticsearch {
   server 127.0.0.1:9200;
}


server {
   server_name _;
   listen 8080;
   location / {
     limit_except HEAD {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/passwd/.esnginx;
     }
     proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
     proxy_redirect off;
     proxy_set_header Host $host;
     proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  location /_aliases {
   auth_basic "Restricted";
   auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/passwd/.esnginx;
   proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9200;
   proxy_redirect off;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }

  include /etc/nginx/auth/*.conf;
}
```

If try: bin/magento config:show catalog/search/engine

> Result: elasticsearch7

If try: curl -i localhost:9200/_cluster/health?pretty

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
content-length: 461

{
  "cluster_name" : "magento2",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 1,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 1,
  "active_primary_shards" : 3,
  "active_shards" : 3,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 3,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0,
  "task_max_waiting_in_queue_millis" : 0,
  "active_shards_percent_as_number" : 50.0
}
```

And if try in web:
[Configuration by web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NCDvB.png)

elasticsearch.yml:
[elasticsearch.yml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEfHk.png)

Comment: Problem is selinux, solved

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue. For me it was a compatibility issue with [Smile-SA
/elasticsuite](https://github.com/Smile-SA/elasticsuite).

The workaround was to delete 'vendor/smile' folder, and do `composer dump-autoload`. (I know it is not a permanent fix, that what I have for now)